# Prevent Default Action on Hyperlink to Run AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a hyperlink on my page

```
<a id="delete-file" href="">
 <img border="0" src="images/delete_.png" alt="Delete File" width="20" height="20" />
</a>
```

I'm trying to prevent the default action when it is clicked and run an AJAX function instead. For some reason when I click it, it just brings me to the top of the page and my my AJAX is not fired. No console error messages either.

Can someone help me with my syntax?

```
<!---Script to upload file link --->     
<cfoutput>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('##upload-file').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.each($('##upload')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file-0', file);
                ajaxUpload(formData);
            });

        $('##delete-file').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
                ajaxDelete();
            });

function ajaxUpload(formData) {
            console.log("ajaxUpload function called");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "actionpages/file_upload_action.cfm?ticket_id=#url.ticket_id#",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('.loader').show();
                },
                complete: function(){
                     $('.loader').hide(3000);
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("File successfully sent.");

                    $("##addFileResponse").append( "File successfully sent." );
                    PopulateFileUploadDiv();
                    },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });

function ajaxDelete() {
            console.log("ajaxDelete function called");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "actionpages/delete_attachment.cfm?ticketID=#URL.ticket_id#&file_path=#filecheck.file_path#",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('.loader').show();
                },
                complete: function(){
                     $('.loader').hide(3000);
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("File successfully deleted.");

                    $("##addFileResponse").append( "File successfully deleted." );
                    PopulateFileUploadDiv();
                    },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }); 
</script>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Incorrect selectors? `#delete-file` instead of `##delete-file`

Comment: Remove the href as you already binding the click event to it and also make the selector valid as Alex.K suggested

Comment: Your id's have double hash signs. That's why the element isn't found and no event is bound to it.

Comment: I have to use a double-pound sign there (##delete-file) because I have ColdFusion output code on the page. If I don't double-pound it, the ColdFusion server thinks I am trying to pass output to it.

Comment: @BrianFleishman Would be helpful if you posted what's actually sent to the browser, then.

Comment: @Bharath - If I remove the href, it is no longer clickable.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - My page seems to just refresh when I click the link. So consequently the Network tab in google chrome just gets refreshed. The console tab doesn't show any errors.

Comment: As suggested, please post the page output HTML, rather than the source. Save-As from the browser will show us what the jQuery is seeing.

Comment: I notice you seem to support multiple file upload. Is there only one delete button? Please do show the output HTML instead :)

Comment: Does your javascript console show any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so my assumption of the error relating to the fact that my AJAX calls lost their uniqueness because the code for the AJAX was outside of my  was correct. I basically had to ajust my code so that I  my AJAX code was within my  tag, but more importantly, that the functions were giving unique names and were passing the unique data from my  output.

Here is my modified and correct code:

```
<cfoutput>
        <table width="50%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
            <tr bgcolor="##CCCCCC">

                <td width="8%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="67%" ><strong>Filename</strong></td>
                <td width="18%" ><strong>Actions</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <cfloop query="filecheck">

              <tr bgcolor="###iif(currentrow MOD 2,DE('ffffff'),DE('efefef'))#" class="btnav" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='##FFFFCC';"
onmouseout="style.backgroundColor='###iif(currentrow MOD 2,DE('ffffff'),DE('efefef'))#'">

                <td><img src="images/Paper-Clip-icon.png" alt="Attachment" /><br /></td>
                <td><a href="https://#subscriber.hostName#.#subscriber.baseURL#/ticket-uploads/#filecheck.file_path#" target="_blank">#filecheck.file_path#</a>
                &nbsp;
                (Record-ID &nbsp; #ID#)
                </td>
                <td>
                 <a id="delete-file#ID#" class="delete-btn#ID#"  href="">
                <img  border="0" src="images/delete_.png" alt="Delete File" width="20" height="20" />
                 </a>

                 <!---Script to upload file link  --->   
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".delete-btn#ID#").on("click",function(e){
                        // ajaxDelete();
                        console.log("Start of prevent.");
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log("Calling AJAX with id of #ID#.");
                        ajaxDelete#ID#();
                    });

                function ajaxDelete#ID#() {
                            console.log("ajaxDelete function called");
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: "actionpages/delete_attachment.cfm?fileID=#filecheck.ID#&ticketID=#URL.ticket_id#&file_path=#filecheck.file_path#&techID=#url.techID#&TT=#type.TT#",
                                data: #filecheck.ID#,
                                cache: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                                beforeSend: function(){
                                    $('.loader').show();
                                },
                                complete: function(){
                                     $('.loader').hide(3000);
                                },
                                success: function(data) {
                                    console.log("File successfully deleted.");

                                    $("##addFileResponse").append( "File successfully deleted." );
                                    PopulateFileUploadDiv();
                                    },
                                error: function(data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                    $("##addFileResponse").append( "Something went wrong." );
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                </script> 


                </td>
              </tr>
            </cfloop><br />
        </table>
        </cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click","##delete-file",function(e){
    ajaxDelete();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Try placing any div wrapping the ##delete-file (loaded before the DOM) that you might have in place of the document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#wrapper-div").on("click","##delete-file",function(e){
        ajaxDelete();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

If you can't get it to work with the ID because of Cold Fusion, try adding a class to the link:

```
<a id="delete-file" href="" class="delete-btn">
```

And then try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete-btn").on("click",function(e){
        ajaxDelete();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: `return false` does the same as `preventDefault()` (and `stopPropagation()`). How will this change help?

Comment: Yeah, answers with code and no explanation are not as useful

Comment: This answer produces the same result. My page just refreshes.

Comment: You need to find a container div that was loaded before the DOM and put that in place of the document.

Comment: @FirstLegion: That suggestion would just speed up the selector, but not change the behavior of a delegated event handler.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie But it could be a problem with it being unable to "find" the div?

Comment: Unless something in the DOM stops the event from propagating, it will always get to `document`. I am just saying your latest fix makes no difference to your previous suggestions. The problem lays elsewhere.

Comment: @FirstLegion I have tried both examples, but they don't seem to prevent the default action. My browser still tries to follow the link in my AJAX function ajaxDelete();

Comment: What do you mean "tries to follow the link"? Does the page go to the URL in the ajaxDelete() function instead of loading it with AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very long shot but I think the problem is that you are not escaping all of your hash signs. Notice at your urls:

```
url: "actionpages/delete_attachment.cfm?ticketID=#URL.ticket_id#&file_path=#filecheck.file_path#"
url: "actionpages/file_upload_action.cfm?ticket_id=#url.ticket_id#",
```

You are escaping the hash sign for your ids but not there so I'm guessing your server is malforming your Javascript, creating an error and preventing the code from executing. You should try double-pounding them too.

If it's truly an issue with the Id, then maybe you can use other jQuery Constructor like this:

[jQuery ( element )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-element)

```
$(document.getElementById('delete-file'));
```

Comment: I think my hash signs are correct. The text wrapped in pound signs are ColdFusion variables. That is the reason I need to double-pound my javascript var's so that ColdFusion doesn't interpret them as possible CF variables.

Comment: Then I think you should really put the parsed HTML. Just open up the browser, click on View Source Code and put the Javascript here. Also check your browser's console to check any possible javascript errors.

Comment: There is a large amount of HTML on the source. Do you just want the HTML pertaining to this issue? Also, I think I have an idea of what is going on. I think that my AJAX call is failing because my processing page is erroring. To clarify, my links I use to call my AJAX are dynamically generated by looping through my database output. Each iteration of the loop generates a unique link that the processing page uses to delete a specific record in my DB. When I remove my ref="" details and put the link in the AJAX call instead, I loose my uniqueness becasue the ajax call is outside the loop.

Comment: I think it would be best if you put all the code. If your AJAX fails it shouldn't make everything else stop working. If there's an error on any part of the Javascript code, then it might stop everything else. Even the AJAX.